# How can I generate 30 random numbers from 1 to 100 in PHP

Tags: php

I want to generate 30 random numbers from 1 to 100, and avoid a number from getting generated twice. So for example, out of the 30 random numbers, the number 9 won't be generated more than once.

How can I do that?

Comment: Where is your code that is trying to achieve that?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: 1/ Log each result : if you already have this result generate a new one, 2/ Create a static array with all numbers from 1 to 100, pick one inside then unset it from the array and start again 30 times...here is 2 ideas, good luck

Comment: @B001ᛦ `rand(1, 100);` - I made this, it only generates 1 number out of 100 and doesn't check if it was already repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep adding numbers until there are 30, each time use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) to get an unused random number between 1 and 100.

```
$random_numbers = [];
while(count($random_numbers) < 30){
    do  {
        $random_number = mt_rand(1,100);    
    } while (in_array($random_number, $random_numbers));
    $random_numbers[] = $random_number;
}

var_dump($random_numbers);
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I get other strings https://i.imgur.com/o3oTioP.png
how can I only show the generated numbers without the "array (size=30)", "0 =>", etc text as shown in the linked picture

Comment: foreach ($random_numbers as $random_number) { echo "{$random_number}\r\n";} //if viewing on web then use "<br>" instead of "\r\n"

Answer (score 6):

An efficient approach could be:

- You can generate a [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) of numbers from 1 to 100.
- Random [Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array.
- Select first 30 values out of randomised array, using [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function.

It shall be random and distinct values. Try:

```
// Generate an array of numbers from 1 to 100
$numbers = range(1,100);

// Random shuffle the array
shuffle($numbers);

// Take first 30 values out of the array (it will be random and distinct)
$random_30 = array_slice($numbers, 0, 30);
```

Comment: i see, this is also a nice method